# Flutter: Create page widget as number of list size in PageView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying create a a pages in view pager as many as the number of item in the list of my object:

```
class WebViewPagerBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic result;
  const WebViewPagerBuilder({this.result});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductNeedConfigModel items = result["Data"] as ProductNeedConfigModel;
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: result["Data"].data.length,
        itemBuilder: (contex, index){
          [
           ...items.data.map((item){
             return ConfigWebViewScreen(result);
           })
          ];
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside ConfigWebViewScreen class i have webview but my codes doesn't work and webview isn't shown?

********* Edit*****************

If i change my builder to this :

```
  body: PageView.builder(
      itemCount: items.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (contex, index) => 
          ...items.data.map((item) {
            return ConfigWebViewScreen(result);
          }).toList()
      ),
```

a read line appear under `...items` section and shows this error:

```
Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.
Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
body: PageView.builder(
      itemCount: items.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (contex, index) => ConfigWebViewScreen(items.data[index]),
        ),
      ),
```